# Are Heroku instances persistent? (Or, can I use dict/array as a cache?)

Tags: python, heroku, instance, newrelic

So my friend told me that instances on Heroku are persistent (I'm not sure if the vocab is right, but he implied that all users share the same instance).

So, if I have `app.py`, and an instance runs it, then all users share that instance. That means we can use a dict as a temporary cache for storing small things for faster response time.

So for example, if I'm serving an API, I can maybe define a cache like [this](https://github.com/karan/HNify/blob/master/app.py#L11-L28) and then [use it](https://github.com/karan/HNify/blob/master/app.py#L60-L67).

How true is that? I tried looking this up, but could not find anything.

I deployed the linked API to heroku on 1 dyno, and with just a few requests per second, it was taking over 100 seconds to serve it. So my understanding is that the cache wasn't working. (It might be useful to note here that majority of time was due to [request queueing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-queueing), according to new relic.)

Comment: If you want to use cache, use redis or memcached. Werkzeug has cache option. But storing to file is not an option. Heroku filesystem ephemeral, which means file system will be different after read and write.

Comment: I concur with kracekumar above. Plus, file caching will always be much slower than memory caching, so I'd definitely look into memcached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Heroku Devcenter has several articles about the [Heroku architecture](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-architecture).

Processes don't share memory. Moreover, your code is [compiled into a slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) and optimized for distribution to the [dyno manager](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#the-dyno-manager). In simple words, it means you don't even know which machine will execute your code. Theoretically, 5 users hitting your app may be routed to 5 different machines and processes.

Last but not least, keep in mind that if your app has only a single web dyno running, that web dyno will sleep. You have to have more than one web dyno to prevent web dynos from sleeping. When the dyno enter the sleep mode, the memory is released and you will loose all the data in memory.

This means that your approach will not work.

Generally speaking, in Heroku you should use external storages. For example, you can use the [Memcached add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier) and store your cache information in Memcached.

Also note you should not use the file system as cache. Not only because it's slower than Memcached, but also because the Cedar stack file system [should be considered ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Comment: Great answer; especially the web dyno part. +1 from me.

Comment: But memcached uses the same memory for all , say, 5 different machine? Or is the memcached addons that use the cloud as a "virtual" memory?

Comment: @KaranGoel memcached *is* shared, because it's an external service. It does not use dynos' memory.